# vite - insert base-url in 404.html

Tags: vite

I have a vite-react app. During build I want to specify the base-url.

In my `index.html` vite automatically injects the base-url (`--base []`) parameter during build.
(`<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />` => `<link rel="icon" href="/my-website/favicon.ico" />`)

how can I achieve that for a `404.html` file?

ps. I don't want include these js and css like vite does in the `index.html`

```html
<script type="module" crossorigin src="/my-website/assets/index-b22f2f26.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/my-website/assets/index-1c1f2add.css">
```

My Current: `/public/404.html` file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="{import.meta.env.BASE_URL}/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#90caf9" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="my website"
    />
    <title>404 - not found</title>
  </head>
  <body style="background-color: #4f4f4f; color: white; min-height: 100vh; display: grid; place-content: center;">
    <img src="{import.meta.env.BASE_URL}/404.gif" alt="404 Page Not Found" style="height: 50vh; width: auto; max-width: 90vw;" />
  </body>
</html>
```

[vites documentation](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#public-base-path) says "JS-imported asset URLs, CSS url() references, and asset references in your .html files are all automatically adjusted to respect this option during build." but it doesn't seem to work for my `404.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally found an answer:

`public/404.html` has to be moved to the root directory besides `index.html`

`vite.config.ts` has to be adjusted to be modified by adding

```js
export default definePlugin({
  ...
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      input: entryPoints(
        "index.html",
        "404.html",
      ),
    },
  }
})
```

together with the helper function

```js
import { join, parse, resolve } from "path";

function entryPoints(...paths) {
  const entries = paths.map(parse).map(entry => {
    const { dir, base, name, ext } = entry;
    const key = join(dir, name);
    const path = resolve(__dirname, dir, base);
    return [key, path];
  });
  
  const config = Object.fromEntries(entries);
  return config;
}
```